# Screen share shortcut

Tags: dell, shortcuts

Hi I have a dell g3 15 3579 running Ubuntu 18.04 I dropped something in the screen and it is unusable now.

I want to be able to screen share with a monitor I have however I can’t login or find a shortcut that works for me.

Can anyone suggest a way to screen share before login screen please.

Comment: Is the monitor plugged in to the laptop? If so there is usually a function key combo to select external monitor... Fn+F3 (from memory) but see this reference https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/fr/fr/frbsdt1/g-series-15-3579-laptop/dell-g3-3579-setupandspecifications/keyboard-shortcuts?guid=guid-204082c4-b0bb-4b16-b60d-563e5cbcd785&lang=en-us

Comment: I have monitor plugged in via hdmi as this is the only external video port available. I tried fn + f8 however this does not work for me and that is only option is link you provided I can see.